# Using an Alias in PostgreSQL query returns "column does not exist"

Tags: sql, postgresql, alias, calculated-columns

I'm trying to get the result of a calculated column in PostgreSQL using aliases from other select queries. I want to divide totalScore by totalEmployee to get the average for the section. But when I try to perform the calculation I get an error.

```
SELECT
    cast( sum( empskills.score ) as dec( 2 , 1 ) ) AS totalScore,
    skills.skill_name,  
    (SELECT
        count(employees.first_name)
        FROM
        sections
        INNER JOIN employees
        ON sections.id = employees.section_id
        WHERE
        sections.id = 2) as totalEmployees,
    (SELECT totalScore / totalEmployees) as finalResult
FROM
    employees
    INNER JOIN empskills
     ON employees.id = empskills.empid
    INNER JOIN skills
     ON empskills.skillid = skills.id
    INNER JOIN sections
     ON employees.section_id = sections.id
WHERE
    sections.id = 2
GROUP BY
    skills.skill_name
```

```
ERROR:  column "totalscore" does not exist
LINE 17:  (SELECT totalScore / totalEmployees)
```

I expected to have the results of the division equation.

Comment: You should define the `totalScore` and `totalEmployees` in a subquery, and then you can use these alias in a outer `select` query, understand?

Comment: I'm new to SQL. How would you do that?

Comment: I think your SQL could be written more beautiful and concise, if you can clarify your requirement clearer, I think I can give you a better SQL.

Comment: Could you give sample data and your desired result.. It will help us to help you too.. You can use this to create your case.. https://dbfiddle.uk/

Comment: I need to get an average per skill for the entire section. I've tried using avg(empskill) but it only shows the average for people that have that skill. Not the average including everyone in the entire section. That means the results are skewed

Comment: @SeekerC see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

According to your SQL above, I think you just want to get the average score for every skill of each employee, I tried to write a more concise SQL as below according to your SQL above:

```
select
    s.skill_name,
    sum(k.score) as totalScore,
    count(distinct e.id) as totalEmployees,
    sum(k.score*1.0)/count(distinct e.id) as finalResult
from
    employees e
join
    empskills k on e.id = k.empid
join
    skills s on k.skillid = s.id
where
    e.section_id = 2
group by
    s.skill_name
```

Comment: @GordonLinoff  the `sections` is joined by `employees`'s section_id.

Comment: @GordonLinoff so the `sections` is superfluous, I have just removed it. :)

Comment: @GordonLinoff but as above, the filter condition just use the column `section_id` which is belong to `employees`.

Comment: Good evening !  Hah,My place is in the morning now. :)

Comment: that gets me the same result as I had. Unfortunately it only averages the number of employees that have a certain skill. It doesn't give the average for the entire section.

Comment: select
    s.skill_name,
    sum(k.score) as totalScore,
    count(distinct e.id) as totalEmployees,
    sum(totalScore*1.0)/totalEmployees as finalResult
from
    employees e
join
    empskills k on e.id = k.empid



Can I use a query like this? Assuming I have subquery with some other JOINs in alias 'totalScore' & 'TotalEmployees' rather than just counts

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-SELECT

this example, .... is more useful in our case, .. I'm having some subqueries to get data from the third table, where there is no sense to make it in Join, but just to get some data... so I'm having the same situation defined in the question. And I needed to use those subqueries output at multiple places, how can I not write the same query at multiple places but reuse the column alias in the same select query ....